# How to recognize all halting states of a turing machine?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

Given a turing machine with some states, how can I recognize all halting states of that machine?

I think that I should go over each state and check if there is a transition that is not defined for that state with one (or more) of the tape alphabet symbols (also containing the blank symbol).

Would this be a good approach?

Comment: Halting states are defined as such in the definition of the Turing machine. See (here)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition] for the formal definition.

Comment: @Ronald: It's undecidable whether for a given machine $M$ and a state $s$ there is an input for which $M$ will reach $s$ (halting or not, it doesn't matter). Also, there is some confusion with terminology here, because sometimes the "halting state" are **defined** to be a set of states, such that if the machine reaches one of them, it immediately halts – by design.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you, so my problem is actually undecidable.

Answer (score 2):

A turing machine is defined as a 7-tuple $M = \langle Q, \Gamma, b, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F \rangle$. The set $F$ in the tuple is the set of *final states* or accepting states. So any other states other than the ones in $F$ are the rejecting states. You can consider the language that $M$ covers as $L$. So $L'$ will be the language (set of phrases) that $M$ never accepts. If you create another Turing machine $M'$ for $L'$, then the set of *final states* for $M'$ in combination with $F$ is the answer you are looking for.

But determining whether or not your Turing machine *ever reaches* these states is another question overall. It is generally impossible to know whether or not a Turing machine will halt beforehand. So if you could count the number of ways that a Turing machine *will* halt (not *could* halt), you are basically raising a serious contradiction with the halting problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do however not really get why the set of final states for ′ (from a totally different machine than M) in combination with  could be of any use? I am interested in the states of M where we can possibly end up after reading a word, even though that state is maybe not a final state.

Comment: @Ronald Well, the machine can halt at any state given the input. If it halts at all.